# fetch data from a network to feed k6 tests

Tags: performance, k6

I wanted to parametrize data in k6 and [looked at the documentation](https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/), as well as other sites , but, I didn't find anything that used async/await syntax. Although, it does [have a lifecycle method](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/test-lifecycle/), and using the `k6/http` module, I might be able to do the request.
But, what if I have to clear/create a database schema , or use an `ORM` query in the setup method of `k6`? They all require some form of promises, [which k6 doesn't seem to support?[2018 ref.]](https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/779). How do I achieve this?

Comment: 2018 is quite old (4-5 years!!!). k6 has started implementing event loops as of v0.37 (March 2021). We are now at v0.42. But why would web requests require promises? k6 can do web requests just fine without async.

Comment: @knittl , what's the usual way to interact with the database? In api dev. it would be an ORM, and most of them work with the usual promises

Comment: Usually you don't, because this would require exposing direct access to the database. Can't you import a database dump before running the test or inserting data via your API?

Comment: yeah, i mean that'd be a manual process, maybe some scripting could help, but, I wanted to do something like just run : `k6 run my tests` and it would be doing that.
I woudn't mind exposing the database, as this would only run on the test server

Comment: if you server on deployed on aws. then you can fetch data and make it k6 tests